# Nothign showing on SQL fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT BachelorsDegrees.Name, BachelorsDegrees.BachelorsDegrees, 
       College_Data.City
FROM BachelorsDegrees
   LEFT JOIN College_Data ON College_Data.City=BachelorsDegrees.Name
WHERE BachelorsDegrees.BachelorsDegrees = :SelectedDegree 
   && College_Data.City = :SelectedCity
```

I have multiple tables.

BachelorsDegrees is one table
College_Data is another table
BachelorsDegrees is a column inside of the BachelorsDegrees table (yes, I named the column the same name as the table but it represents the course names under that degree type)
City is a column inside the College_Data table
Name is a column inside the BachelorsDegrees table

Basically the search form allows the user to find a college based on: Degree type, City, and Course name.

If the Degree type is "Bachelors Degree", the query will go into the BachelorsDegrees table, searches for the colleges/universities that matches the course name, then goes into the College_Data table and then finds the colleges/universities that matches the city.

So the City and Course Name MUST match.

Problem is, when I test the search form, nothing shows up on the results page.

My fetch code looks like this:

```
try {

    $query = $db->prepare($query);
    $query->execute($params);
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
    //foreach ($query as $row) {
        //echo 'College Name: '.$row['Name'];
        //echo '<br /> Accreditation: '.$row['Accreditation'];
        //echo '<br /> Term Type: '.$row['TermType'];
        //echo $userSelection;
        //echo $selectedCity;
    //}
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Unable to fetch Degrees!: ".$ex->getMessage()."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: This join condition certainly doesn't look right to me:  `College_Data.City=BachelorsDegrees.Name`.

Comment: Is `$params` defined? try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of the page

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @Matt - yes it is defined.  No errors on the page.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - any suggestions?

Comment: Sidenote: you sure have a lot of unaccepted questions. We don't know if any or all have provided you with solutions. They should be marked as solved, otherwise Stack thinks they're unsolved at this point.

Comment: As Gordon said in the begining `College_Data.City=BachelorsDegrees.Name` cannot be right, not even in the world of illogically named columns you seem to inhabit

Comment: @Fred-ii- most people tend to give me "go to this site and read more.  you'll learn how to solve your problem" answers.  I would not be helping people if I marked something down as solved if it didn't really solve the problem.  though I might have to go back and check.  a lot of answers solve only a small aspect of the problem but not the entire problem and the person who posted never replies back.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - "illogically named columns"  what do you mean by that?

Comment: "cannot be right" doesn't really point me in the right direction.

Comment: Quote _So the City and Course Name MUST match_ where is the logic there. What has a City got to do with a Course?

Comment: cuz basically the college city in one database has to match the course name of the college in the other database.  eg: database table 1 has "University of Manila=Manila" then database table 2 should have "University of Manila=IT" if the user is searching for an IT college in Manila.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The City and the Course name of the College are in separate tables.  When a person searches for a college, the City they choose and the Course name they choose should be aligned to the same college, therefore both database tables need to be queried.

Comment: I understand. Many a times, people offer links in order for them to hopefully find the info they need in order to debug. Usually, they come back and tell us that what they tried didn't work and also don't show us what it is they tried along with any errors they may be getting. More often than none, we are left to guess what the problem is, and have to setup a db / php code to test it on our end. That isn't always pleasant to do, since they'll either run off or say *"it doesn't work"*. We try to help as much as we can.

Comment: well for this particular problem, I've given as much info as I can.....is there anything I am not providing that is preventing anyone from pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to realize too that since you have College_Data.City in the where you have effectively turned your left join into an inner join.

Comment: "you have effectively turned your left join into an inner join" what does  that mean?  basic English please :)

Comment: Even if I replaced LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN, doesn't seem to do anything.  Not sure if my query has a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Now you would be use this script your problem will be solve :

```
        $st = $db->prepare($query);
        $st->execute();
        $results = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        print_r($results);
```

Comment: how is that different from the code I currently am using? print_r isn't displaying anything for me at the moment.

Comment: You have to check your $query is run direct in database if it is not working so correct it